# How to filter on 2 records in microsoft dynamics nav

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I want to set a filter on 2 fields of a record in microsoft dynamics nav.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
//set filter on the fields "Location Start" that are not blanco.
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location Start",'<>%1','');
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location End",'<>%1','');
```

I need to set the filter on "Location Start" as well as on "Location End"

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Customer DO BEGIN
  FILTERGROUP(-1);
  SearchString := '@*ou*';
  SETFILTER(Name, SearchString);
  SETFILTER(Contact, SearchString);
  SETFILTER(City, SearchString);
  IF FINDSET THEN
    REPEAT
     MARK(TRUE);
    UNTIL NEXT = 0;
  FILTERGROUP(0);
  MARKEDONLY(TRUE);
  PAGE.RUN(0,Customer)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as you wrote it.
You selected the wrong record?
If you're on a page, use `SETFILTER("Location Start", '<>%1', '');` directly instead of using `Rec.SETFILTER` ...
Can you give a bit more context what doesn't work or what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually I did not explain my self very well. 
If myRecord."Location Start" OR myRecord."Location End" is not blanco OR myRecord."Location Start" AND myRecord."Location End" are not blanco, then I want for example to CLEAR the data

Comment: So you're using this in a code?

If you need "Location Start" = '' AND "Location End" = '' then you can apply the filter SETRANGE("Location Start", '') SETRANGE("Location End",'')

If you need the filter "Location Start" ='' OR "Location End" = '' then you have no other choice than use 2 record variables and loop each of them.
Rec1.SETRANGE("Location Start", '');

If (Rec1.FINDFIRST()) THEN REPEAT

  .. do you code here

UNTIL (Rec1.NEXT() = 0)
Rec1.RESET();
Rec1.SETRANGE("Location End", '')
If (Rec1.FINDFIRST()) THEN REPEAT
  .. do you code here
UNTIL (Rec1.NEXT() = 0)

Comment: Yes I am using this in the code unit. Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location Start",'<>%1',0D);
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location End",'<>%1',0D);
```

0D is the way of setting a null date

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to find if your date is between Start Date and End Date, so you do need to write as following,...

```
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location Start", '>%1', you_date);
myRecord.SETFILTER("Location End", '<%1', you_date);
If myRecord.ISEMPTY then FALSE
  ELSE TRUE
```